# The Ubuntu logo looks square

Tags: 22.04

Is it normal that the logo is displayed square in the "about system" settings or is it a mistake ?

In general, the Rom is fine, thanks for fixing a lot of errors that I earlier received. The update was painless for additional software and correct.
Wi-fi and Bluetooth work, I did the battery calibration by resetting the BIOS to the default settings after each battery charge cycle.
For the first time I saw what the Grub screen looks like and much more...
But I have doubts about the logo. Will it always be like this, or is this a temporary solution under development ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjgAE.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/585pJ.png)

Comment: yep that's Ubuntu's new logo

Comment: Thank you, accepted, but I have little reputation to thank for the help. I've been pressing thumbs up for 24601 and you.

Comment: I do not undertake to discuss the creator's decision, I just wanted to clarify, because I get errors with google pictures (avatars). I thought there was something wrong with the Ubuntu logo too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is is the correct style for the logo for v22.04 and is at it appears when starting the system.

[image]